# Hive velocity stream - Reactive Java or Kafka Streams

Tags: java, spring-boot, concurrency, reactive-programming, apache-kafka-streams

I have a high velocity endpoint with a certain payload.
I have 800 listener threads active on a queue.
I then need to generate events from that payload. There can be X amount of events from each payload.
I then need to aggregate these events into buckets of Y that will be sent to another service via http. 
The HTTP calls take time so i need them to be async and in parallel (additional Z amount of threads to make these calls.
The flow needs to be highly efficient.

What I have right now is this.
The http listeners call a service which generates the events and puts them into a ConcurrentLinkedQueue 
then call a ResettableCountDownLatch.countDown (set to wait for Y).

I have a thread pool where each executor awaits for the ResettableCountDownLatch then checks if the queue has more than Y, if yes then polls Y events from the queue and does the call.

I would love to hear if there is more efficient way to work here, any open source projects that fit here (I heard of Reactive (on spring boot 2), or Kafka Streams)

```
doneSignal = new ResettableCountDownLatch(y);
executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(senderThreads);
    executor.submit(() -> {
        while (true) {
            try {
                doneSignal.await();
                doneSignal.reset();
                if (concurrentQueue.size() > bulkSize) {
                    log.debug("concurrentQueue size is: {}, going to start new thread", concurrentQueue.size());
                    executor.submit(() -> {
                        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        while (concurrentQueue.size() > bulkSize) {
                            List<ObjectNode> events = populateList(concurrentQueue, bulkSize);
                            log.debug("got: {} from concurrentQueue, it took: {}", events.size(), (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
                            String eventWrapper = wrapEventsInBulk(events);
                            sendEventToThirdPary(eventWrapper);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Kafka itself? This is basically a multi-threading question, including proper use of count down latches.

Comment: Its relation to Kafka in only since it gets the initial payload from kafka. And so if there  is an efficient way to achieve this based on the fact that would be great. that said its not a kafka question.